# Connect to Athena using SQL workbench

Tags: amazon-athena

I am trying to connect to Athena using SQL workbench. I followed all the instructions from page 15 to 19 mentioned in this PDF file:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.7/docs/Simba+Athena+JDBC+Driver+Install+and+Configuration+Guide.pdf

If I use the default athena bucket name, I get this error:

S3://aws-athena-query-results-51346970XXXX-us-east-1/Unsaved

> [Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been thrown from the AWS SDK
>   client. Unable to execute HTTP request: No such host is known
>   (athena.useast-1.amazonaws.com) [Execution ID not available]

For any other bucketname I get this error:

s3://todel162/testfolder-1

> [Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been thrown from the AWS SDK
>   client. Unable to execute HTTP request: athena.useast-1.amazonaws.com
>   [Execution ID not available]

How do I connect to Athena using JDBC client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using copy-paste had an issue with the string on page 16:

```
jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=useast-1;
```

It should have a - like this...

```
jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-east-1;
```

Once I corrected this, I was able to connect.